# .Net Core and Microsoft.Web.Administration

Tags: c#, .net, ssl, iis

I am trying to write a service that can add bindings to IIS on a remote srver. I am using Microsoft.Web.Administration.
My code to add the bindings looks like this:

```
    public static bool AddSiteBinding(string siteName, string ipAddress, string tcpPort, string hostHeader, string protocol)
    {
        try
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(siteName))
            {
                throw new ArgumentNullException("siteName", "AddSiteBinding: siteName is null or empty.");
            }
            //get the server manager instance

            using (ServerManager mgr = ServerManager.OpenRemote(@"\\Qasql01\c$\Windows\System32\inetsrv\config\applicationHost.config"))
            //using (ServerManager mgr = new ServerManager())
            {
                SiteCollection sites = mgr.Sites;
                Site site = mgr.Sites[siteName];
                if (site != null)
                {
                    string bind = ipAddress + ":" + tcpPort + ":" + hostHeader;
                    //check the binding exists or not
                    foreach (Binding b in site.Bindings)
                    {
                        if (b.Protocol == protocol && b.BindingInformation == bind)
                        {
                            throw new Exception("A binding with the same ip, port and host header already exists.");
                        }
                    }
                    Binding newBinding = site.Bindings.CreateElement();
                    newBinding.Protocol = protocol;
                    newBinding.BindingInformation = bind;
                    site.Bindings.Add(newBinding);
                    mgr.CommitChanges();
                    return true;
                }
                else
                    throw new Exception("Site: " + siteName + " does not exist.");
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw new Exception(ex.Message, ex);
        }
    }
```

The problem is that this code (which works fine locally) blows up with an `Object reference not set to an instance of an object.` error when it's run against the remote server. The remote server in this case is IIS 8.5 on Windows Server 2012. I have tried every solution I can find without any luck at all. I am running this code from VS 2017 which is running as an administrator. Here's what I've tried:

1. Verified that the IIS management tools are installed on the server
2. Verified that DCOM is configured and added a specific endpoint in ahaadmin
3. Turned the firewall on the server off.
4. Turned off UAC
5. Verified that I have the right version of Microsoft.Web.Administration DLL
6. I have tried entering the IP address, the remote path to the config on the server, and the server name.

I cannot test my solution on my local machine because the versions of IIS are different. Ultimately I will be writing code to add an SSL certificate to the "Central Certificate Store" which is an IIS feature not available in Windows 10. I really need "OpenRemote" to work, but it seems like it doesn't. There are no examples from Microsoft for the ServerManager.OpenRemote() method. The examples that I have found simply don't work (most reference IIS7). I'm beginning to think the OpenRemote method was never tested in anything above IIS7.
Is anyone out there successfully using ServerManager.OpenRemote() against IIS 8.5?

Update: Here is a pic of what I see in VS in debug:
[image: VS Debug]

Comment: Which MWA? You cannot use the NuGet version.

Comment: What line blows up with the null reference exception?

Comment: @virusstorm The line directly after the using statement that instantiates `mgr`. Of course you can't access `mgr.Sites` because mgr is null, it never gets created. 

@Lex Li I am using version [11.0](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Web.Administration/) of the NuGet version which according to Microsoft is compatible and works with .Net core. In October of 2016 Microsoft took over MWA and made it an official NuGet package. So it's now owned and maintained by Microsoft.

Comment: Microsoft took over that NuGet package for a completely different purpose (IIS REST API), so still you shouldn't use it that way, https://blog.lextudio.com/whats-microsoft-web-administration-and-the-horrible-facts-you-should-know-b82f2c974da6

Answer (score 4, accepted):

OK I just figured this out. First, I am convinced that OpenRemote DOES not work. The article I read showed examples of OpenRemote passing in the config file--which is not right. After digging around a bit in MS code I see that there is a constructor that accepts the applicationHost.config path, but not a version of OpenRemote that accepts a config path. It's possible that this may have worked in IIS 7 and an earlier version of MWA but certainly not this version. Of course, passing in Server or IP doesn't work either. I changed the line that instantiates the ServerManager to:

```
using (ServerManager mgr = new ServerManager(@"\\qasql01\IISSharedConfig\applicationHost.config"))
```

and now it works. This seems to be the only way to configure a remote server. At least this way allows you to use plain ole file security and bypass all the DCOM mystical security requirements.

Comment: It is still the wrong approach. You might use `ServerManager` to parse the config file and modify some settings, but going without the DCOM interface leaves all your changes on that file, and can break certain MWA functionality (site start/stop for instance) as that constructor is designed for local config file.

Answer (score 4):

As far as I understand, [ServerManager.OpenRemote()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.web.administration.servermanager.openremote(v=vs.90).aspx) is meant to take the server name, not the path to applicationHost.config. Maybe that was the issue?

It stopped working for me when I upgraded the Microsoft.Web.Administration NuGet package. Works fine when I downgrade back to version 7.0.0.0.

Answer (score 1):

I can confirm that the answer from user2033791 works like a charm (IIS8.5/2012R2). The remote IIS systems automatically pickup the extra bindings and other applications are not recycled.

The constructor used is hidden with the `[Browsable(false)]` attribute and according to MSDN is for Microsoft Internal Use Only. So buyer beware ;-)

References:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.web.administration.servermanager.servermanager(v=vs.90).aspx
https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#Microsoft.Web.Administration/Microsoft/Web/Administration/ServerManager.cs,d3122afbddb2cfa0

Comment: This should have been a comment on the other answer instead of an answer, as you're not providing an answer yourself, but adding to an existing answer.

Comment: I did want to comment but I am not allowed to comment except on direct reply's and my vote up is also not visible. Because few people use this library i wanted to make sure that everyone will know that the given answer works and provide additional relevant details.

Comment: You might check the comment I left under user2033791's answer. This approach is incorrect.