# IIS-based web site can't connect to a remote server

Tags: asp.net-core, iis

I have to write a program in .NET Core that will create (from code) an IIS website on remote server.

Code I am using:

```
var serverManager = new ServerManager(Environment.SystemDirectory + "\\inetsrv\\config\\applicationhost.config");
ApplicationPool newPool = serverManager.ApplicationPools.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Name == siteName);
if (newPool == null)
     newPool = serverManager.ApplicationPools.Add(siteName);
newPool.ManagedRuntimeVersion = "v4.0";
Site site = serverManager.Sites.Add(siteName, "http", "*:80:" + siteName, physicalPath + @"\" + siteName);
site.ServerAutoStart = true;
site.ApplicationDefaults.ApplicationPoolName = siteName;
serverManager.CommitChanges();
```

That works on local server but I can't rewrite this to connect to the remote server and create a page there.

Comment: [Get started with .NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/get-started?tabs=windows)

Comment: install plex on server or use file server by git are pest. to use this code you must have access on machine.config and application config i don't know how strategy work in your company maybe anther one can help you. best regard

Comment: Set up IIS REST API and then talk to that. MWA is in general .NET Framework only.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried the `OpenRemote` method in the `ServerManager`

`public static Microsoft.Web.Administration.ServerManager OpenRemote (string serverName);`

Check [docs here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.web.administration.servermanager.openremote?view=iis-dotnet).

You can find some good examples [here](https://www.csharpcodi.com/csharp-examples/Microsoft.Web.Administration.ServerManager.OpenRemote(string)/)

Another good idea I came up to was to create an api/service/ local application with TCP connection on that will accept a message and will run the code on the server. Found it here. Though with impersonation of local admin,  you can get the job done. 
https://forums.iis.net/t/1162205.aspx

Comment: I have tried that before (with server name and ip address) but it return only NullReferenceException :/ maybe something with permissions on server?. is it possible to use this method with login and password (something like connString)?

Comment: No. It should work in the same domain via NTLM. Extensive comments on how to login to another remote out of the domain can be found https://forums.iis.net/t/1162205.aspx

Comment: this server is on the same domain as mine local computer, but for some reason I can't connect to it

Comment: Check the event viewer in the remote machine for any errors.

Comment: Also check that the firewall for DCOM is enabled http://mvolo.com/connecting-to-iis-70-configuration-remotely-with-microsoftwebadministration/

Comment: i found a similar problem on [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47480571/net-core-and-microsoft-web-administration)
I will try to do the same

Answer (score 0):

<sub>OP's solution moved from question to answer:</sub>

> I finally used WMI to connect to IIS server. Probably not the best option but working for me.